# Sum of values in Python, excluding equal values

Tags: python, addition

Return the sum of 3 numbers, but if they're the same, they dont count towards the total. Can you help me find what's wrong in my code please?

```
def lone_sum(a,b,c):
    t=0
    if a==b and a!=c:
        t=a+c
    elif a==c and a!=b:
        t=a+b
    elif b==a and b!=c:
        t=b+c
    elif b==c and b!=a:
        t=b+a
    elif c==a and c!=b:
        t=a+b
    elif c==b and c!=a:
        t=b+a
    elif a==b and b==c:
        t=a
    return t
```

Comment: In general, you should show an example of when it's not giving you the right output. That being said, the solutions that have been provided are a big step up for clarity and efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution:

```
def lone_sum(a, b, c):
    return sum({a, b, c})
```

Comment: The explanation for how this works is that the curley brackets ```{}``` are creating a set, which is "an unordered collection with no duplicate elements."

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it within two lines of code by using `set` like this

```
def lone_sum(a,b,c):
    return sum(set([a,b,c]))
```

This much more efficient than all the above codes. I suggested this because i believe programming is meant to solve problems efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

```
def lone_sum(a,b,c):
    if a==b and a!=c:
        t=a+c
    elif a==c and a!=b:
        t=a+b
    elif b==a and b!=c:
        t=b+c
    elif b==c and b!=a:
        t=b+a
    elif c==a and c!=b:
        t=a+b
    elif c==b and c!=a:
        t=b+a
    elif a==b and b==c:
        t=a
    else:
        t = a + b + c
    return t
print (lone_sum(21, 32, 32))
```

There's nothing wrong with your code, I think you forgot to call the function. 
I also added some small features to your code.